# How to customize bootstrap tabs when active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i try to make a website, when the one of bootstrap tabs was selected it will show just like their id name. but when the tab selected it cant set to active. so i think i can make custom active class to span when selected. So, how to customize tabs when it selected. maybe like change span bg color when selected

My bootstrap code, Someting like this

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <span data-toggle="pill" href="#lorem" class="btn btn-lg btn-default team-name">Lorem</span>
    <span data-toggle="pill" href="#ipsum" class="btn btn-lg btn-default team-name">Ipsum</span>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="lorem" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="text-center head-text">
            <h3>Lorem</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ipsum" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="text-center head-text">
            <h3>ipsum</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h
Is this your requirement?

Comment: @samuellawrentz yeah, something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want like this:-

```js
$('.tabsBtn').on('click', '.btn', function(){
 $('.tabsBtn .btn').removeClass('activeClass');
 $(this).addClass('activeClass');
});
```

```css
.activeClass{ background:green !important; color:#fff !important;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 tabsBtn">
    <span data-toggle="pill" href="#lorem" class="btn btn-lg btn-default team-name">Lorem</span>
    <span data-toggle="pill" href="#ipsum" class="btn btn-lg btn-default team-name">Ipsum</span>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="lorem" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="text-center head-text">
            <h3>Lorem</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ipsum" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="text-center head-text">
            <h3>ipsum</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, just like what i want

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `span` you could use `li`. Only then bootstrap will be able to add `active` class to the active pill.

Also to style it, you must override the bootstrap's default styling. So give an `id` to the pill container and then you could overide the styles you wish.

For reference https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h

```css
#pills li.active>a{
background:red;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<div id= "pills" class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Bootstrap only recognizes `li` for navigation between pills. View this line from their code https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/a5d48323a2bb4600fe6d53b5a881e1386e46e9ce/js/src/tab.js#L45

If you have to use `span` you must make alterations to this file which is not advisable.
You can still style the `li` as you wish.

Comment: so, i cant use span ?

Comment: You can, but why? It is kind of complicated. I have added the reason in the answer edit.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript/jQuery part you can add a class active on click and then using css add style

```
jQuery('.team-name').on('click',function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    jQuery(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
}
```

In CSS

```
team-name.active{
    background-color:#efefef;
}
```

Comment: now it can add class to selected span, but it not remove the class when i click to another span

Comment: this line is to remove active class from other tabs.... if you haven't changed the structure of html 
jQuery(this).siblings().removeClass('active');